# configuring VPN with DHCP

Tags: vpn

We have configured a VPN server and DHCP and assigned the clients address range as 10.10.1.10-20. The DHCP server is given the router address as 10.10.1.1. When I connect using VPN client the VPN server is giving out the address of 10.10.1.10 as the IP address and gateway but this should be 10.10.1.1. DHCP address given to the clients in the range of 10.10.1.10-10.10.1.20

I have two NIC, once static and another as private. I have used the various options in Routing and Remote access but could not get this done. Now I am having the access to servers share however I need to browse the share on the client that is dialed into the server.

Any ideas highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to assign different iP info to the client? is this causing an issue? I don't see the point of your first paragraph as you don't say that it is causing an issue.
have you tried accessing the client share? what happened? And did you try it from the VPN server or another PC on the network?#

Answer (score 0):

For the VPN connection, the default gateway is the DHCP assigned ip address for the VPN connection as you're seeing. That's normal and sounds like it's working as expected. You need to enable LAN routing on the RRAS server in order for the VPN client to have access to any other share or computer on the LAN. I'm not sure if that will allow a LAN client to access a share on a VPN client but it will allow the VPN client to access a share on a LAN client.